# intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS , no sound on Debian 110.0 bullseye

Tags: linux, debian, audio, hardware, intel

i have installed Debian 11.0 bullseye and the sound is not working
the speaker and microphone are not detected
my sound card is Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS

kernel details

`uname -a`

```
Linux debian 5.10.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.136-1 (2022-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

full hardware probe can be found [here](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=b4bfab8974)

`lspci`

```
0:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
```

`alsactl init`

```
alsa-lib parser.c:260:(error_node) UCM is not supported for this HDA model (HDA Intel PCH at 0xb121c000 irq 148)
alsa-lib main.c:1014:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:1 use case configuration -6
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel Kabylake HDMI" "HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x152d" "0x125d"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

by runnig the above commands i noticed the Found hardware was "Intel Kabylake HDMI"

but my sound car is **Intel Cometlake** and the driver is snd_hda_intel

listing playback Hardware Devices

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

searching online for a fix here is what i tried

1. adding kernal argument **snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0**
   to the grub boot menu by editing the
   /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"

updating grub and reboot

the result is NO SOUND

notice that the sound work fine using bluetooth headset
or usb  headset or HDMI cable

2. adding kernal argument **snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1** in the same way
   as above

after making sure that the **firmware-sof-signed** package is installed

this time the driver changed to **sof-audio-pci**
and i can see differend playback Hardware Devices

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but still NO SOUND

notice that the sound work fine using bluetooth headset
or usb  headset

my question is

**How to get the sound working for the build in speakers and microphone ?**

Comment: Try kernel 6.2.1, if it doesn't work, file a bug report here bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: Or 6.1.14 - it's still supported.

Comment: ok i will try the kernel 6.2.1

Comment: i tried version 6.2.1 and the issue remains :-( see https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=cdaf43afa8

Comment: Please file a bug report.